# Cannot convert physical disk to vhdx (Hyper-V)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hyper-v, disk-image

I have used Hyper-V Manager for more than two years to backup my two-partition external HDD to my computer (~600 GB [BitLocker encrypted] + ~100GB [unencrypted]). [Here is a step-by step tutorial](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458344.aspx), on how to do it. This method was very convenient, since you are saving whole structure with full encryption and saving it to a single, expandable file (if used space is less than 700GB, the backup image will also take less space). Plus, if you want, you can attach it to your PC and use it as a virtual disk.

However, starting about two months ago, I could not copy the physical drive during the same method, always ending up with the following error:

```
[Window Title]
New Virtual Hard Disk Wizard

[Main Instruction]
The server encountered an error trying to create the virtual hard disk.

[Content]
Failed to convert the virtual disk.

The system failed to convert '\\?\scsi#disk&ven_st<some-ID>'.

[Expanded Information]
Failed to convert the virtual disk.

The system failed to convert '\\?\scsi#disk&ven_st<some-ID>': The request is not supported. (0x80070032).

[^] Hide details  [Close]
```

[image: Error image]

I have tried it on another Windows 10 machine - same error.

I have also tried [Disk2vhd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458344.aspx) utility from Microsoft - also getting an "Error snapshotting volumes".

I have no clue, why this happens, since the disk is the same, with the same partitions. But it does not work anymore.

P.S.: if you are using some other method for backing up the whole physical disk/partition, please share! :)

Comment: You might have two unrelated problems. For Disk2vhd, try it without the option of "Use Volume Shadow Copy". For Hyper-V, try to uncheck the ‘backup’ option in the VM’s Hyper-V integration settings.

Comment: Thank you, @harrymc.
Disabling the Disk2vhd "Use Volume Shadow Copy" option allowed me to clone the drive (currently cloning). However, I had to unlock the encrypted partition. Will the imaged VHD include the encryption?

Regarding Hyper-V - I do not have any VM attached. I only use the Hard Disk image wizard to copy contents of my external HDD. I did not find that option anywhere else.

Comment: So Disk2vhd is solved. The 0x80070032 error seems to be related to disk/folder permissions - check that that some folder or account permissions haven't changed, or maybe try to run the backup as admin.

Comment: What the... One moment, after many many tries, there was no error.. And Hyper-V successfully started the conversion process. I cancelled it just to try, if it works again - and it didn't. I got the same failure error, but with different code and message - Incorrect function. (0x80070001).

Comment: This error is also related to disk problems. I would suggest to do chkdsk and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I ran the service a few times, there were some problems fixed. However, I still get the same error, on both of my Windows 10 Pro computers - tested with 3 different external storage devices.

Comment: Getting errors is pretty bad - there should be none - so it may be a synptom of the problem, or maybe the fix wasn't enough. But I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, for the Disk2vhd utility getting the error of
"Error snapshotting volumes" :

Disabling the Disk2vhd option of "Use Volume Shadow Copy" allows to clone the drive.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I hope I will be able to deal with Hyper-V problem somehow and will write the correct answer. Should I mark this as an answer, or just edit my question to reflect your solution (since the main problem isn't fixed)?

Comment: You have my permission to edit my answer if you wish, although I think it would be more correct to have your findings under your own name.